# css centering dynamic div horizontally(not working)should be simple

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that through jquery is being dynamically inserted into another div like so

this is the jQuery:

```
$('#portSecW div:not(".closeXbtn")').prepend('<div class="portSecRollOver"><div class="portSecInner"></div></div>');
```

this is regular the HTML:

```
<div class="portThumbsL">
<a href="images/sitePortThumbs/2882.png"><img src="images/sitePortThumbs/2882.png" alt="2882films"/></a>
<div class="thumbTxtSmall">2882FILMS</div>
```

the final output is this

```
<div class="portThumbsL">
<div class="portSecRollOver"><div class="portSecInner"></div></div>
<a href="images/sitePortThumbs/2882.png"><img src="images/sitePortThumbs/2882.png" alt="2882films"/></a>
<div class="thumbTxtSmall">2882FILMS</div>
```

Im doing this to animate a rollover effect im shooting for etc...in the middle of
portSecInner is where other dynamic content is inserted etc...(just text)
The parent of .portSecInner is portSecRollOver and that is absolutely positioned.

So the problem im having is that in the css i have a simple

```
.portSecInner{ margin:0px auto !important;}
```

but it doesnt center it...doesnt even move it. Now when i target it manually 
for example ( margin: 10px 20px ) etc, it moves but obviously, doesn't center everything.

Any ideas as to what i can do to correct this and get this baby centered???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto` will work only after setting a `width` for the element and it's parent, like this:

```
.portSecRollOver {
    width: 300px;
}
.portSecInner {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: you know i JUST saw it and fixed it. Cambe back to answer my own and there you go, you beat me to it lol. i coulda SWORE i had set a width....sigh....getting tired lol. Thanks

Comment: Yeah... answer ninja! You saved two minutes of your time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Closing tag of `<div class="portThumbsL">` is missing. Close this and try.

margin:0 auto is working I guess. Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/85s4j/1/

If you dont want to fix the width for `portSecInner` then add the `margin:0 25px;` so that you can get the div to the center of the parent div

Comment: sorry bad copy/paste i fix it on the post. nice catch but that aint it. not sure what the prob is